# Can you use arrow functions in this situation?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, this, arrow-functions

I haven't worked much with just vanilla javascript for DOM manipulation, but following some tutorials I see some stuff like this for example:

```
const video = document.querySelector('.video');
function toogleState(){
  if (this.paused) {
  //Do something here
  }
}

video.addEventListener('click', toogleState);
```

My questions is, how would I access the this.paused if I want to use arrow functions?

Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: makes no sense? I can't access the normal this in an arrow function so how do I access the pasued property on the clicked element?

Comment: You can use anywhere you want arrow functions, they're an alternative to the old school way to declare a function .

Comment: @AndreiShadowS how do I access the paused property of the clicked element if I use an arrow function? I can't use this in an arrow function.

Comment: While it's possible with an arrow function, just don't do that and use a normal function. Why do you *want* to use an arrow function?

Comment: @AndreiShadowS No, they're not "*an alternative*" that works anywhere, and `function`s are definitely not "*the old school way*". Arrow functions just offer a nicer syntax for some very specific cases of function usage.